# Replace text in a string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

In the below text, how do I replace :

`ABCDEFG` with `XYZ`

> http://url/#/rep/dip-rep?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:e:!f,value:'ABCDEFG'),query:(match:(sv:(query:'ABCDEFG',type:phrase)))))

Comment: the question is so messed up. pls arrange the question. i cant even try to fix it because the change  might the ruin essence of the question

Comment: It looks like people became absolutely confused about `JavaScript != jQuery`. This question has nothing do with the second one, it is a pure JS problem.

Comment: ironically, your question almost answers itself......"replace ABCDEFG with XYZ"  -----> `.replace('ABCDEFG', 'XYZ')`

Comment: @DelightedD0D, your suggestion did not work. any thoughts?

Comment: Judging by the answer you selected, the reason it did not work was because you did not state that you wanted to replace **every occurrence** of `ABCDEFG` which is an important distinction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should Try this

```
"YourText".replace(/ABCDEFG/g,'XYZ');
```